# Import multiple video in blender vse

Tags: video-sequence-editor

When i try to import multi footage to VSE via Add->Movie. The result is shown in the picture. is there any efficient way to add multiple footage without this problem?

[image]

Comment: It's doing this because the length of the audio doesn't match that of the video. If you change Blender's framerate to match the vids it should work fine

Comment: You can use MediaInfo to get the framerate of the source materiale: https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo and set the project framerate in Blender accordingly.